# How to solve for discrete state space matrices given input and output

Tags: mathematics, linear-systems, linear-control

I have a set of time-series data that consists of inputs $u_k$ where $ 
u \in R $ and $k = 1 ... T$, and outputs $ y_k $ where $ y \in R^2 $ and also $k = 1 ... T$, from a given system. I believe this system can be modeled in discrete canonical state space form as
$$ x_{k+1} = Fx_k + Gu_k $$
$$ y_{k+1} = Cx_{k+1} $$
In this case, $ y_{k} = x_{k} $ so the form becomes
$$ y_{k+1} = Fy_k + Gu_k $$
Given all of the $ y_k $ and $ u_k $ I am fairly sure that I should be able to solve for $ F $ and $ G $, but how do I actually do this? Some work on paper got me nowhere and I can't seem to find anything on the internet.

Comment: The general topic is "System Identification", but I think for success you probably need some idea of what your system is. Me being me I'd switch to the frequency domain and get a transfer function. https://au.mathworks.com/help/ident/gs/about-system-identification.html

Comment: **1** Is $F$ a $2\times 2$ matrix ? **2** are the measurements $y_k$ noisy ? i.e. $y_{k+1} = Cx_{k+1} + \mathbf{w_{k+1}}$ where $w$ is unknown noise.

Comment: @AJN 1) Yes 2) yes but negligibly so, which is why I excluded it.

Comment: OK, so what are the dimensions of y and u?

Comment: Have you seen papers using Hankel matrices and Singular value decomposition methods like these ? [1](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=A+Subspace+Fitting+Method+for+Identification+of+Linear+State-Space+Models&btnG=), [2](https://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/SystemID/References/Tether-IEEE-TAC-1970.pdf), [3](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1524/auto.1966.14.112.545/html)

Comment: There are lots of open-source implementations of identification of linear statespace models, here's one https://baggepinnen.github.io/ControlSystemIdentification.jl/dev/ss/ in Julia that has a permissive license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this turned out to be to frame the problem as a least-squares problem. Specifically I found & used [State Space Model Identification by Least Squares](http://paginapessoal.utfpr.edu.br/avargas/courses-1/identificacao_sistemas/identificacao_sistemas/1_materialApoioStateSpace.pdf). This allowed me to solve for the rows of $F$ and $G$ one-by-one.